# How to solve undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

view page:

```
 @if(count($applications)>0)
<table class= "table table-striped">
 <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
     <th>Date Applied</th>
     <th>Leave Type</th>
     <th>Leave Status</th>
     <th></th>


 </tr>
 @foreach($applications as $application )
 <tr>
    <td>{{$application ->user->email}}</td>
    <td>{{$application ->dateApplied}}</td>
    <td>{{$application ->leaveType}}</td>
    <td>{{$application ->leaveStatus}}</td>
    <td>
     {!!Form::open(['action'=>['ApplicationAdminController@destroy', $application ->appId], 'method'=>'DELETE'])!!}
     {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
     {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
     {!!Form::close()!!}
    </td>


</tr>
 @endforeach
</table>
```

controller:

```
 public function  destroy($appId)


{

    $application = Application::find( $appId);
    $application ->delete();

 $this->deleteLeave($appId);
    return redirect('/applicationAdminHistory')->with ('success', 'Application Removed');
}

public function deleteLeave($appId){

    $user_id = Auth::id();
    $req = DB::table('leave_summaries')
    ->where('user_id',$user_id)
    ->increment($leaveType,$day);

    }
```

What I want to do is when click delete button the application will deleted and will do increments at the leave_summaries table. The increment at the leave_summaries based on the value of day and leave type in the application that has been deleted. After i run this code i got undefined variable error as shown below:

[image: result after run this code]

Comment: In your `deleteLeave` method, there is no `user_id` variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

In this Code Please Pass $user_id , $leaveType ,$day:

```
 public function deleteLeave($appId){


        $req = DB::table('leave_summaries')
        ->where('user_id',$user_id)
        ->increment($leaveType,$day);

        }
```

Comment: Please explain how to do this

Comment: You Can use Auth::user()->id as $user_id , but $leaveType and $day need to pass when method is calling

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it. Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from it

Comment: " The increment at the leave_summaries based on the value of day and leave type " where you find value of day  and leave type ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't defined these three variables : $user_id, $leaveType, $day

You need to pass these values as parameters into the deleteLeave() method or these values had to be defined before the method called.

```
public function deleteLeave($user_id, $leaveType, $day){
    $req = DB::table('leave_summaries')
        ->where('user_id',$user_id)
        ->increment($leaveType, $day);
}
```